# regex working not as expected javascript, displays wrong values

Tags: javascript, regex

i have string `"This auction will run from Friday 28 July - Monday 7 August. It will close from 7pm (GMT) on Monday 7 August 2023. Read here for information on how our auctions end."`

and im trying to get dates from this string

```js
const str = "This auction will run from Friday 28 July - Monday 7 August. It will close from 7pm (GMT) on Monday 7 August 2023. Read here for information on how our auctions end.";
const regex = /(\d{1,2} \w+(?: \d{4})?)/g;
const dates = str.match(regex);
console.dir(dates);
```

this is regex that i wrote and in regex checker site((\d{1,2} \w+(?: \d{4})?)) it matches for  28 july, 7 august and 7 august 2023, but in javascript it only matches for 7 august and 7 august 2023, whats wrong?

Comment: Matching all three dates for me.

Comment: Your snippet works fine. You can hit the "Run code snippet" button and verify for yourself.

Comment: @connexo https://imgur.com/a/avbLmBo